# How can I test that Javascript rendered :nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, functional-testing

If I have an action that should render nothing for certain Javascript requests, how can I test that that's what it did?

That is, if the action is:

```
def some_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :nothing => true if some_condition }
  end
end
```

...how can I write a functional test to verify that it really did render nothing?

Edit: `assert /\A\s*\z/.match(@response.body)` asserts that the body contains only whitespace, is that testing the right thing?

Comment: How can one tell if something truly is nothing while still observing it?  Deep philosophy that one rarely finds on SO....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert /\A\s*\z/.match(@response.body)` asserts that body contains only whitespace, which appears to be the simplest approach to this problem. More specific tests run into issues, since it apparently puts some odd whitespace characters into the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert_nil @response
```

should work, though you might need to do

```
assert_same @response, ""
```

instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get `Expected "" (oid=33492012) to be the same as #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x3fcbec8
 @blank=true,
 @block=nil,
 @body=[" "],
 @cache_control={},
 @charset="utf-8",
 @content_type="text/javascript",
 @etag=nil,
 @header={"Content-Type"=>"text/javascript; charset=utf-8"},
 @length=0,
 @request=
  #<ActionController::TestRequest:0x3fcc1b0
   @cookies={},
   @env=
    {"rack.version"=>[1, 1],
     "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x3fd57e0>,` (it keeps going from there, tons of info). Also didn't work: `assert @response.blank?` which the first part encouraged me to try.

Comment: Close. Remove your ?. assert response.blank or assert response.blank == true or something like that.

Comment: @response.blank gets me an UndefinedMethodError.

Comment: Taking a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html, you should do `assert_same @response.body, ""` or potentially `@response.body.first`

Comment: `assert_same "", @response.body` gave `Expected " " (oid=33590052) to be the same as "" (oid=33590124).` while `assert_same "", @response.body.first` gave `Expected " " (oid=33051180) to be the same as "" (oid=33051252).`

Comment: `Expected " " (oid=33051216) to be the same as " " (oid=33051300).`

Comment: My goal was to point you in the right direction, you'll need to handle tweaking to make it work yourself... Give http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#assertions-available a look.